# How to sum the value of a key across all documents in a MongoDB collection via mongotemplate?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

my collection:

```
{
"_id":"5c2f0013f573b0fb2864d6cd",
"vin":"4JGBB56E39A518216",
"chargeTime":6000,
"chargeAmount":5,
"date":"20181001"
}
```

I want to sum "chargeAmount" in all this collection via java spring mongoTemplate
like

```
agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(

Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("date").gte(beginTime).lte(endTime)),

Aggregation.group("_id").sum(analyzeField).as("amount"),

Aggregation.project("amount").and(countField).previousOperation()
            );
```

but it doesn't work.

And I have tried $group in mongodb shell:

```
$group{
  _id: '',
  chargeTime:{$sum: '$chargeTime'}
}
```

it works.

So how to performance in mongotemplate? Thanks

Comment: what output would you expecting ?

Comment: do summing operation on all "chargeAmount" field in one collection